# Change value of outerscope variable inside a function

Tags: node.js

The following code has two variables, `id_client` and `id_ped`. I cannot change the value of both variables, how can I make that happen?

```
function verify(phone){
  const client_phone = phone;
  var id_client = 0;
  var id_ped = 0;
  connectToDB().then(connection => {
    const query1 = queryCliente(connection, client_phone)
    query1.then(cliente => {
      if(cliente){
        id_client = cliente[0].idCliente;
        
        const query2 = queryPedidoCliente(connection, id_client);
        query2.then(pedido => {
          id_ped = pedido[0][0].idPedido
          console.log('Id Client Inner: '+id_client)
          console.log('Id Pedido Inner:'+id_ped)
        });
      }
      connection.end();
    });
  })
  console.log('Id Client Outer: '+id_client)
  console.log('Id Pedido Outer:'+id_ped)
}
```

Result

```
PS C:\MyNodeJSApps\Test> node index.js
Id Client Outer: 0
Id Pedido Outer: 0
Id Client Inner: 1
Id Pedido Inner: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are mutated from inside of an asynchronous closure. So your 2 lasts console logs (which are synchronous) are executed before the async closure. So you have to make sure you wait for the promise resolution before using your muted variables.

```js
function verify(phone){
  const client_phone = phone;
  var id_client = 0;
  var id_ped = 0;
  connectToDB()
    // this will be executed after the current synchronous function is ended.
    .then(connection => {
      const query1 = queryCliente(connection, client_phone)
      query1.then(cliente => {
        if(cliente){
          id_client = cliente[0].idCliente;
        
          const query2 = queryPedidoCliente(connection, id_client);
          query2.then(pedido => {
            id_ped = pedido[0][0].idPedido
            console.log('Id Client Inner: '+id_client)
            console.log('Id Pedido Inner:'+id_ped)
        });
      }
      connection.end();
    });
  })

  // This is executed first, the asynchronous callstack comes after.
  console.log('Id Client Outer: '+id_client)
  console.log('Id Pedido Outer:'+id_ped)
}
```